# Where to order whole-wheat flour(NOT ATTA) in India?

Tags: substitutions, milling, wholewheat

Many people are deceived that maida(7.5% gluten) is ALL PURPOSE FLOUR and atta is WHOLE WHEAT FLOUR((10-12%)gluten but starch is lost due to chakki milling) so there is actually a lot of difference and simply one can't be substituted for another. I'm writing this so that many people don't think that I do not have access to atta. So if a bread recipe calls for whole-wheat flour, where can I buy it or order it in non metro cities like Chandigarh at "reasonable prices".
KAF is simply too high in terms of Indian money and the same is with Bob's red mill or Pillsbury, Gold Medal whole-wheat flour.
Out of them Gold Medal brand is the cheapest 626 rupees for 5lbs

Comment: Your question is very broad, check [ask] to understand what kind of questions you can ask here

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The  question has been edited accordingly

Answer (score -1):

We buy wheat grains and get it milled at a local flour mill. This way we can ensure the texture that we desire and also the quality. Time consuming but worth it. Not to mention the reduced cost.

Comment: Reduced cost !?!?!!?